# Visual Studio 2010 Exceptions dialog is empty (as of today)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Starting today, I noticed that the Exceptions dialog within VS2010 appears empty, and I can therefore not make any selections within it. I am not sure where to go to begin trying to fix this, as I see no error or anything. This has previously worked. Following is a screenshot:

[image]

I have tried checking if any updates were installed recently (none were), and no new updates are available. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: interesting to know why it happened..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try starting visual studio in safe mode by starting it with the [`/SafeMode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) command line option. Once open, see if the exceptions are there - changing a setting here may reset the view back when you start Visual Studio normally.

Alternatively, try resetting Visual studio back to its original settings by starting it with the [`/Setup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6a2fad%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) command line option.

Comment: I tried both (/SafeMode didn't help - VS opened and said it was in Safe Mode, but the behavior didn't change), but when I start with /Setup, nothing seems to happen. VS doesn't open, and no windows appear.

Comment: Actually, after having run with /Setup (even though nothing seemed to happen) the next time I run VS my Exceptions dialog populates as it should. Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Mark: `/Setup` does not run Visual Studio (ie. start it), it just resets the settings.

Comment: That would certainly explain what happened. Thank you again.