# vs2010 "Modify Style" Dialog box has no textboxes to enter values

Tags: html, visual-studio-2010, stylesheet

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to build a web application. When I click bring up the "Modify Style" dialog box to modify the style of an html tag, there are no text boxes to enter values. Is there a fix for this issues. I am using VS2010 on a Windows Server 2003. I do not see any values in the "Modify Style" dialog box. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I was able to fix this issue was to reformat the computer and re-install the OS.

Answer (score 0):

[I had a similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876216/visual-studio-2010-exceptions-dialog-is-empty-as-of-today) in a different dialog, and starting VS with the /Setup argument fixed it for me.

Comment: Sorry, that did help. I still get the same issue. I will upload an image of my issue.

Comment: I got a link to the image of the issue.