# How to start WindowsForms app?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, nuget

I did something and the play arrow is not active :| any ideas how to make it active again? both in Release and Debug mode :(

It has happened after I have added NuGet and log4j.net. I have no errors messages and even in meny the run is disabled. In Debug menu I only have Start Performance Analysis, Attach to process(and others that are not Start Debugging).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

do you have a start project and start form set?  That's most likely the issue.  Right-click on your start project and set it as start project.  Then choose the form you want to be the start form and set it to the start form.

Comment: Glad it was something simple!

Answer (score 2):

You could try starting VS with the [/Setup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex6a2fad%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) option as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876216/visual-studio-2010-exceptions-dialog-is-empty-as-of-today) question.

Otherwise, [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vsdebug/thread/cb10e83a-70b6-43b4-9527-dc5ce9115dcf) person had the same problem because they had multiple startup projects, and one of them was non-runnable. Could this be the case?

Answer (score 1):

Or you may simply use the shortcuts: F5 and CTRL + F5

Also, I've had this problem couple of times. When I select my main starting project or a file in it, it enables the play button again